# Foreach Key/Value pair issue

Tags: java, foreach, key-value

I'm trying to convert a PHP script into a Java one but coming across a few issues on a `foreach` loop. In the PHP script I have a `foreach` that takes the key:value pair and based off this does a `str_replace`.

```
foreach ($pValues AS $vKey => $vValue)
      $vString = str_replace("{".$vKey."}", "'".$vValue."'", $vString);
```

I tried replicating this in Java without success. I need to get the key from the array to use in the string replace function, but can't  find out where or if it's possible to get the key name from the array passed in.

Is this the right way or am I completely off? Should I be using the `ImmutablePair` method?

```
for (String vKey : pValues)
      // String replace
```

Here's hoping there is an easy way to get the key:value pair in Java.

Comment: If you have a Key:Value data structure you should be using a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and not an array. Then you can iterate over the [Entries set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()). If you only want the index number of the array (as the key) you can use a for loop.

Comment: Can you please provide the declaration of pValues?

Comment: Use this reference: [Java: How to Get Keys and Values from a Map](https://stackabuse.com/java-how-to-get-keys-and-values-from-a-map/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help and advice, I've managed to duplicate the function in Java using `Map`.

```
if (pValues != null)
{
  Set vSet = pValues.entrySet();
  Iterator vIt = vSet.iterator();
    
  while(vIt.hasNext())
  {
    Map.Entry m =(Map.Entry)vIt.next();
    
    vSQL = vSQL.replace("{" + (String)m.getKey() + "}", "'" + (String)m.getValue() + "'");
    vSQL = vSQL.replace("[" + (String)m.getKey() +"]", (String)m.getValue());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be acheived by using Map as data structure and then using entryset for iterating over it.

```
 Map<K,V> entries= new HashMap<>();
    for(Entry<K,V> entry : entries.entrySet()){
        // you can get key by entry.getKey() and value by entry.getValue()
        // or set new value by entry.setValue(V value)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible with a simple foreach-loop in Java.

If *pValues* is an array, you could use a simple for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pValues.length; i++)
  // String replace
```

If *pValues* is a *Map*, you can iterate through it like this:

```
for (Key key : map.keySet())
    string.replace(key, map.get(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

Group Totals
Have the function `GroupTotals(strArr)` read in the `strArr` parameter containing key:value pairs where the key is a string and the value is an integer. Your program should return a string with new key:value pairs separated by a comma such that each key appears only once with the total values summed up.

For example: if strArr is `["B:-1", "A:1", "B:3", "A:5"]` then your program should return the string `A:6,B:2`.

Your final output string should return the keys in alphabetical order. Exclude keys that have a value of 0 after being summed up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).